# Expl3 calculate dimension ratio as int/decimal

Tags: expl3

I have to calculate the ratio of two dimensions, and display it (possibly as the rounded int value).

I don't know how to produce the best MWE but here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{}{%

\dim_ratio:nn{\columnwidth}{\textheight}

}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\test

\end{document}
```

Outputs:

> 22609920/36044800

And now I'm stuck since I don't know how to make it calculate the ratio, nor I am able to set it to a floating point variable e.g. via

```
\fp_new:N\l_my_fp
\fp_set:Non\l_my_fp{\dim_ratio:nn{\columnwidth}{\textheight}}
```

Since I get an error:

> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   !
>   ./Senza-titolo.tex:13: LaTeX error: "kernel/misused-fp"
>   ! 
>   ! A floating point with value '0.6272727272727273' was misused.
>   ! 
>   ! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
>   ! 
>   ! For immediate help type H .
>   !...............................................

Comment: You don't need to load `expl3` when `xparse` is used -- `xparse` **is** an `expl3` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I did not know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than one way, I think.

If you want to have an expandable way, `\fp_eval:n {\dim_ratio:nn{}{}}` (shortened) is enough, you don't need `\NewDocumentCommand` for this then.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

 \fp_new:N \l_moriambar_ratio_fp 

 % Expandable: 

\cs_new:Npn \calctheratio #1#2 {%
  \fp_eval:n {\dim_ratio:nn{\columnwidth}{\textheight}}
}  


\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{}{%


\fp_set:Nn \l_moriambar_ratio_fp  {\dim_ratio:nn{\columnwidth}{\textheight}}

\fp_use:N \l_moriambar_ratio_fp


}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\test

\calctheratio{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that was easy...

Comment: @Moriambar: *Sometimes* `expl3` is quite easy...

Answer (score 1):

There is not need for `expl3` here at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\test{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr\columnwidth/\strip@pt\textheight\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test

\end{document}
```

Even better:  Use LuaTeX!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\directlua{
  tex.sprint(tex.getdimen("columnwidth")/tex.getdimen("textheight"))
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Background info from chat: The OP is writting a package completely in `expl3`, that's why he asked about about `expl3` way